# Angular 1 bind data to a script template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I am still an upcoming developer and i got a problem here.
I want to bind an item from the main template to a script template which is a form activated via md-dialog. How can I bind data from the outer template to the script template?
I want to bind data from the main template to act as placeholders for the form.

Here is my code snippet.

```
ol(style="font-size: 14px; width: 100%; overflow-y: auto;")
            li(ng-repeat="action in rating.actions" style="margin-bottom: 1em;")
              div.action-items
                div <b>Task:</b> {{ action.task }}
                div <b>Owned by:</b> {{ action.owner }}
                div <b>Due date:</b> {{ action.due_date | date:'medium' }}
                div(ng-switch="action.status") <b>Status:</b> &nbsp;
                  span(ng-switch-when="unresolved" style="color:red;") {{ action.status }}
                     md-button.md-raised(ng-click="showConfirm($event, rating, action.id)" style="margin-left:7px; background-color:green; color:white; min-height: 23px !important; min-width: 46px !important; font-size: 10px !important; line-height: 0px;") Resolve Now
                  span(ng-switch-when="resolved" style="color:green;") {{ action.status }}&nbsp;
                    span(style="color: #757679") by {{ action.resolved_by }}
                a(href="" ng-click="showDelete($event, rating, action.id)")
                  i.fa.fa-trash-o(style="color:red; margin-right: 7px; font-size: 18px")
                a(href="" ng-click="showEdit($event, rating, action.id)")
                  i.fa.fa-pencil-square-o(style="color:black; margin-left: 7px; font-size: 18px")

        script(type="text/ng-template" id="dialogContent.tmpl.html")
          md-dialog(ng-cloak)
              md-dialog-content
                  form(name="editItem")
                  div(layout layout-sm="column")
                  md-input-container(flex)
                      label Task
                      input(ng-model="task" placeholder="{{action.task}}")
                  md-input-container(flex)
                      label Owned By
                      input(ng-model="owner")
                  md-datepicker(flex ng-model="date" md-placeholder="Due date")
                  div(style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; margin-bottom: 3px;")
                  md-button.md-raised.md-primary(ng-click="hide()" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl" type="submit" id="submit" style="margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;") Confirm Edit
                  md-button.md-raised.md-primary(ng-click="closeDialog()" style="margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;") Cancel
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the style of language you're using, but, you need to use the id you gave the script template. So you have:

```
script(type="text/ng-template" id="dialogContent.tmpl.html")
```

So to use that with your ng-repeat, you'd change your line to:

```
li(ng-repeat="action in rating.actions" style="margin-bottom: 1em;"
  ng-include="dialogContent.tmpl.html")
```

Then each repeat will use your scripted template.

Comment: Thanks a lot... let me try and get back to you

Comment: Apparently it does not work. Adding the ng-include makes my actions disappear from their view.